Rewrite dispose of Azure Service bus
I have a class called ServiceBusBackgroundJobManager, it sends messages to Azure service bus
public class ServiceBusBackgroundJobManager : BackgroundWorkerBase, IBackgroundJobManager
    {
        private readonly IAppConfigurationAccessor _configurationAccessor;
        private readonly ServiceBusClient _client;
        private ServiceBusSender _sender;
        private readonly string _serviceBusQueueName;

        public ServiceBusBackgroundJobManager(IAppConfigurationAccessor configurationAccessor)
        {
            _configurationAccessor = configurationAccessor;
            var connectionString = _configurationAccessor.Configuration["Abp:ServiceBusConnectionString"];
            _serviceBusQueueName = _configurationAccessor.Configuration["Abp:ServiceBusQueueName"];
            _client = new ServiceBusClient(connectionString);
        }

        public async Task<string> EnqueueAsync<TJob, TArgs>(TArgs args, BackgroundJobPriority priority = BackgroundJobPriority.Normal,
            TimeSpan? delay = null) where TJob : IBackgroundJobBase<TArgs>
        {
            var messageBody = JsonSerializer.Serialize(args);
            var message = new ServiceBusMessage(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(messageBody))
            {
                MessageId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                ContentType = "application/json"
            };

            if (delay != null)
            {
                message.ScheduledEnqueueTime = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.Add(delay.Value);
            }

            _sender = _client.CreateSender(_serviceBusQueueName);

            using var messageBatch = await _sender.CreateMessageBatchAsync();
            if (!messageBatch.TryAddMessage(message))
            {
                throw new Exception($"Exception");
            }

            try
            {
                await _sender.SendMessagesAsync(messageBatch);
            }
            finally
            {
                await _sender.DisposeAsync();
                await _client.DisposeAsync();
            }

            return string.Empty;
        }

    }
}

The problem is that in the finally block I have dispose, but it will not disposed of in 2 options

So if two or more jobs are about to be enqueued, the second one won't have a client to use.
If no jobs are enqueued, the client doesn't get disposed.

How I need to write code, to make it works in those 2 options?

You are creating the client in the constructor, which means you only want to dispose the client once f.e in a Dispose method of the worker. If you want to dispose it each time, you'll have to create the client each time, which means, in the EnqueueAsync method itself.

You can achieve this in a neater way using Dependency Injection (DI).
There are DI extension methods that will register the Service Bus classes in a safe way and ensure they're disposed at the appropriate time, without you having to worry about it. Here's how to change your code to do this.
1. Set up the DI
In your application startup (e.g. Program.cs) add the DI config. This example is for an Azure Function but it will be similar in other frameworks.
var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWebApplication() // (Depending on your framework)
    .ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        // Use the DI extension method for Azure clients.
        services.AddAzureClients(configureClients =>
        {
            // Add the ServiceBusClient.
            configureClients.AddServiceBusClient("YourConnectionString");

            // Add the Sender for your queue.
            configureClients.AddClient<ServiceBusSender, ServiceBusClientOptions>((_, _, provider) =>
                provider
                    .GetRequiredService<ServiceBusClient>()
                    .CreateSender("YourQueueName"));
        });

        // And then add your service classes, including your Manager class.
        services.AddScoped<IBackgroundJobManager, ServiceBusBackgroundJobManager>();

        // You should also add your other Service classes as DI.
    })
    .Build();

host.Run();

2. Simplify your Manager class
Your Manager class can now just take the Service Bus instances as a Constructor dependency, which the DI will create appropriately. The Manager is no longer responsible the the lifetime of the instances, so it doesn't have to consider Disposal.
public class ServiceBusBackgroundJobManager : BackgroundWorkerBase, IBackgroundJobManager
{
    private readonly ServiceBusSender _sender;

    public ServiceBusBackgroundJobManager(ServiceBusSender sender)
    {
        _sender = sender;
    }

    public async Task<string> EnqueueAsync<TJob, TArgs>(
        TArgs args,
        BackgroundJobPriority priority = BackgroundJobPriority.Normal,
        TimeSpan? delay = null) where TJob : IBackgroundJobBase<TArgs>
    {
        var messageBody = JsonSerializer.Serialize(args);
        var message = new ServiceBusMessage(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(messageBody))
        {
            MessageId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
            ContentType = "application/json"
        };

        if (delay != null)
        {
            message.ScheduledEnqueueTime = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.Add(delay.Value);
        }

        using var messageBatch = await _sender.CreateMessageBatchAsync();
        if (!messageBatch.TryAddMessage(message))
        {
            throw new Exception($"Exception");
        }

        await _sender.SendMessagesAsync(messageBatch);

        return string.Empty;
    }
}

Further reading
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/messaging.servicebus-readme?view=azure-dotnet#client-lifetime

Do you need to create the sender every time? It’s safe to cache the sender or use a singleton for the lifetime of the application. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.messaging.servicebus.servicebussender?view=azure-dotnet

The OP has asked a specific question. Can you please provide a specific answer to that question?

it answers the question as registering Service Bus class as singleton ensures they're disposed properly....
